# Как использовать методы интерфейса без наследования

Tags: c#, ооп

Есть интерфейс

```
    public interface ISourceRepositoryProvider
    {
        IPackageSourceProvider PackageSourceProvider { get; }
        SourceRepository CreateRepository(PackageSource source);
        SourceRepository CreateRepository(PackageSource source, FeedType type);
        IEnumerable<SourceRepository> GetRepositories();
    }
```

Можно ли использовать методы данного интерфеса без наследования от `ISourceRepositoryProvider`. Допустим я хочу использовать метод `CreateRepository` напрямую

Comment: Если честно - вопрос совершенно непонятный, добавьте больше кода и пояснений. Ну вот есть у вас класс SourceRepositoryProvider: ISourceRepositoryProvider - и вы хотите закомментировать что вы отнаследовались от интерфейса? Ну и пусть, просто пропадёт значок с буквой I в исходном коде напротив каждой строки, где методы были реализованы. Ну, тот, который кликнув перейдёшь к определению интерфейса.

Comment: Только если использовать `dynamic`, но вам это не нужно. Используйте всё преимущество статической типизации

Answer (score 6):

Интерфейс не содержит *реализации* методов. На него лучше всего смотреть как на *обещание* класса эти самые методы реализовать.

Поэтому без создания экземпляра *класса, реализующего интерфейс*, обойтись не удастся: имея лишь интерфейс, но не реализацию, вы не получите ваши методы.

---

С другой стороны, вы можете реализовать методы и *не давая обещания* их реализовать, то есть, не объявляя, что ваш класс реализует интерфейс.

В этом случае проблемы могут возникнуть если клиенты вашего кода ожидают реализацию интерфейса, но вы реализовали лишь методы, но не сам интерфейс. В этом случае автоматического «распознавания» не произойдёт: в C# не принята «утиная» типизация.

Comment: "Интерфейс не содержит реализации методов." - пока что)

Comment: @AntonKomyshan: Это да, в C# 8 собираются сломать мой ответ :-)